# Setting os environment variables usable non-dag files managed apache airflow

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I am trying to shift from a docker-based airflow service to managed apache airflow provided by AWS. MWAA requires you to specify a dags folder where all the dags are present. Furthermore, I can create other folders and files inside dags folder and include a .airflowignore file so that these files/folders are treated as non-dag. I can specify some common functions in these files and import them in my dag code in order to use those functions. So far so good. The problem comes when I have to use certain Environment variables in these common non-dag files. I found how to setup runtime os env variables using plugins in from here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/samples-env-variables.html

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
import os

os.environ["PATH"] = os.getenv("PATH") + ":/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages" 
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"]="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.272.b10-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64"
os.environ["My_Var"] = "hello"

class EnvVarPlugin(AirflowPlugin):                
     name = 'env_var_plugin'
```

using this code I have setup an ENV variable My_Var.
My foder structure looks like this

```
dags
|
|-hello_dag.py
|-common
|  |
|  |-varcheck.py
```

in hello_dag.py, I am importing VAR from varcheck.py

```
import os
from common.varcheck import VAR
print(os.environ["My_Var"])
print(VAR)
```

in varcheck.py I am doing

```
import os
VAR = os.environ["My_Var"]
```

I am getting an import error on this

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/hello_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/varcheck.py", line 2, in <module>
    VAR = os.environ['MY_VAR']
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/os.py", line 681, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'MY_VAR'
```

interestingly if I change the varcheck.py file to

```
import os
VAR = os.environ
```

then the code works fine and print(VAR) prints all Environment variables. I want to know how we can use os environment variables in non-dag files in MWAA as this is essential for our implementation.

Edit: Current structure of repo

```
repo
|-common (used by all others)
|-airflow (deployed in ECS)
|-jobs_1 (deployed in batch)
|-jobs_2 (deployed in batch)
|-jobs_3 (deployed in lambda)
```

common files use env variables. If we are to replace them with airflow variables, we would need to maintain separate common files for airflow as job_1, job_2 and job_3 have nothing to do with airflow and they use common files.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are CASE dependent.

Relating to your post:
In your first post code block you are using

```py
os.environ["My_Var"] = "hello"
```

In your stack trace, we are seeing

```
VAR = os.environ['MY_VAR']
```

However, if you plan on using this environment variable on multiple places, but it is not required for airflow to start, you could also consider using an Airflow variable.

Comment: But would I be able to use airflow variables directly in my common files? My goal is essentially to set up variables that I can use directly in my common files.

Comment: Also what did you mean when you said env variables are CASE dependent

Comment: As long as these common files are being executed on the same computer/server you are running an airflow service on (worker/webserver/scheduler), it will work. All it needs really to function is the `airflow.cfg` file and the database connection.

Comment: On MWAA, AWS manages all these things in the background for us. Usually while using airflow, we can set up all these things easily by ourselves. But my query is specifically about MWAA.

Comment: What I meant to say was, as long as you only use these 'common' files from inside MWAA, it would work without a doubt. Given that is the case, using Airflow Variables should be safe for your use case.

Comment: Using Airflow Variables instead of ENV variables in the common files is working for me. But we are not using common files just for airflow. They are being used for our other code as well. If we are to replace every os env usage in common files with Airflow Variables, then we would need to maintain two separate sets of common, one for our usual code and other for airflow. That is why I want make os.environ work in common files instead of shifting to Airflow Variables.

Comment: Alright but it sounds like you just answered your own question. Why would the "other code" be able to read the environment variable from the plugin but not the Airflow Database? Airflow is implemented in such a way that it's either both or none because without database connection there is no way of loading the plugin that loads these environmental variables for you.  --- It sounds like you need a hybrid of Airflow variables (or environment variables) and config files.

Comment: I won't be sharing the same space for my other code as with the airflow code. So right now we have different packages in our repo which all use the common package files. One of them is airflow. All of them exist in different spaces. Currently while creating a docker image out of different jobs, we include the common folder there. Airflow docker is deployed in ECS while other dockers are deployed in other services like batch or lambda. In ECS, we can set ENV variables easily that are usable in common files as well.

Comment: Now if I am to maintain a separate common folder for airflow, we can do that. But then if there is any change in any of the files, we would need to update the same change in airflow common files as well as our usual common files.
Current structure (in edited question)

Comment: Isn't it the also case with these environment variables that you need to configure them on two locations?
To me it sounds like the best solution is to store all variables you are using in a shared python file with global variables (or some fancier construction).

Comment: The thing is that we already have a common file code, which uses environment variables, that we don't want to change. Thats why we want to anyhow make it work using os environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your plugins file.

```
VAR = os.environ["My_Var"]
```

There is no environment variable set up with the name **My_Var**, so it's giving you a KeyError.
Btw you might wanna try Airflow variables.

Comment: Use this to set your environment variable: os.environ['My_Var'] = 'some_value'

Comment: I am already doing it. please check my plugins file code again. What you are referring to is varcheck.py file where I am trying to use the variable I have set up.

Comment: Please read the question thoroughly before answering Mohsin :)